# Confluence docker: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up Confluence by Atlassian via docker-compose (so I dont have it running in the background all the time.)

I know next to nothing about docker - all I know is how to fire up my docker-compose.yml to start up a mysql microservice.

So I tried following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/installing-and-configuring-atlassian-confluence-wi) and I am already failing at step 1. So I tried creating a docker-compose.yml with this content:

```
version: '3'
services:
  confluence:
    image: atlassian/confluence-server
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
      - 8091:8091
  confl-mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=confluence
      - MYSQL_USER=confluence
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=your-password
```

and I am getting this in my terminal:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Building confl-mysql
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

My directory tree looks like this:

```
├── atlassian-confluence-7.4.0-x64.bin
├── conf_dckr_cmp
│   ├── confl-mysql
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── data
│   │   └── confluence
│   │       ├── confl-mysql
│   │       └── Dockerfile
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── mysql
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar
│   └── mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar
├── docker-compose.yml
└── mysql
```

How do I resolve the error shown in my terminal? What does it actually want me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this one.

```
confl-mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
```

instead of this.

```
confl-mysql:
  build: ./mysql
```

Comment: That gives me `ERROR: Service 'confl-mysql' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder926161935/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar: no such file or directory
`

Comment: Jar files in upper directory. Try to put jar files to same folder with mysql Dockerfile.

Comment: It starts up. Ive run into a bunch of other problems but at least it starts up. Thank you!